# Rewrite URL containing directory path and parameters to parameter based URL using both path and query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I use htaccess to rewrite this path:

```
/inventory/products/tools/
```

to this url with query string:

```
/inventory.php?cat=products&type=tools
```

using the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^inventory/(.*)/(.*)/? /inventory.php?cat=$1&type=$2 [L,R=301]
```

When I add a query string to my url path

```
/inventory/products/tools/?sort=pricehigh
```

and use this rule

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^inventory/(.*)/(.*)/? /inventory.php?cat=$1&type=$2&%1 [L,R=301]
```

I am getting a redirect loop and the urlstring is rewritten over and over

I am trying to end up with the following destination url

```
/inventory.php?cat=products&type=tools&sort=pricehigh
```

In the example rule above I am using R=301 in order to visualize the url. 
In a production I would use [L] only

Comment: You don’t need to check if the query string contains anything, remove that condition. Use the `QSA` flag to get the original query string merged with the new one you created.

Comment: (_“I am using R=301 in order to visualize the url”_ - 302 would be better; with 301 you run the risk that the browser _caches_ your redirects, so if you test again after making changes to your rewriting, you might easily get fooled by still seing the “old” result.)

Comment: /inventory/product/tools/?sort=pricehigh

RewriteRule ^inventory/(.*)/(.*)/? /inventory.php?cat=$1&type=$2 [QSA,L,R=302]

using QSA does add the QS but results in product a concatenation of product and tools

/inventory.php?cat=product/tools&type=&sort=pricehigh

Comment: That sounds like more than one round of rewriting is happening, or something else like MultiViews might be interfering (the latter often happens, when you have a partial overlap between the fake path, and existing files, like here with `inventory` and `inventory.php`) Try and disable MultiViews, or rename the script file to something else, and see if that changes things.

Comment: In my rule I use a ? to match when the URL may or may not end in a /. If I remove that the rewrite works. Do I need to use 2 rules - one with a trailing slash and one without?

Comment: Ah, okay. Without the trailing slash, the second `(.*)` also allows for matching _zero_ characters - so due to the greediness of regular expressions, the _first_ `(.*)` matches `products/tools` already. Try and change the `*` to a `+` in both places, to demand at least one character in those positions.

Comment: closer. now there is a trailing slash before the QSA... /inventory.php?cat=product&type=tools/&sort=pricehigh

Comment: `RewriteRule ^inventory/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /inventory.php?cat=$1&type=$2 [QSA,L,R=302,NE]` should work, at least according to https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ (which is not always a perfect indicator though.) Not sure why it seems to need the `NE` flag, tbh. - but without it, I get `?cat=products%26type=...` in the result, the `&` gets URL encoding applied for some reason.

Comment: That works. do you want to add that solution as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the trailing slash, the second `(.*)` also allows for matching zero characters - so due to the greediness of regular expressions, the first `(.*)` matches `products/tools` already.

The following should work:

```
RewriteRule ^inventory/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /inventory.php?cat=$1&type=$2 [QSA,L,R=302,NE]
```

`([^/]+)` demands one or more characters, out of the class of characters that contains everything but the `/`.

The `NE`/`noescape` flag seems necessary here for some reason, otherwise the resulting query string will contain `?cat=products%26type=...`, with the `&` URL-encoded.